# Is there any way that I assign a specific color to my node according to the value present in my list

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, networkx

Or you can say I applied clustering to my data and I want to assign a specific node color to that cluster.how can I do that?

I am unable to do so...please recommend me something.

Comment: Please share your code so that people can better understand your problem. It is not clear from your question as it is as to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear but if I understood correctly you can try putting your points with assigned clusters into pandas dataframe and then plot it with something like seaborn f.e.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,1,1.5,3,4],
                   'Y': [1.1, 1.3, 0.9, -2, -2.1],
                   'clusterId': [1,1,1,2,2]}) 
# Probably you want to start with only X, Y and generate clusterId in some way

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='X', y='Y', hue='clusterId', ax=axes)
plt.show()
```

You can than also adjust colors markersizes styles etc. which you can find how to do in [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) or other stackoverflow questions